# Must I always use a form in a tabular interface in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a list of users that have requested access to my application.

They appear in a table inside a view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <% for ar in @brand.access_requests %>
        <% user = ar.user %>
        <tr id="user_<%= user.id %>">
            <td><%= user.company %></td>
            <td><%= user.first_name %></td>
            <td><%= user.last_name %></td>
            <td><%= user.email %></td>
            <td><%= collection_select :role, :id, Role.all, :id, :name %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "Create", brand_responsibilities_path(@brand), { :remote => true, :method => :post } %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

So I want to assign a Role to each user, then approve that user.

Obviously this does not work, because I do not know how to refer to the "role_id" field from my link_to.

How do I include a value from another field in my link_to? Is there a way to do a ":with" or something like that?  I want to pass whatever is chosen in the select box to:

```
brand_responsibilities_path(@brand)
```

I know it would work if I created a form for every single row, but is that overkill, or the Rails Way?
Any help is seriously appreciated.

Comment: Is there a form tag somewhere in here? I see you are posting via a link, but don't see that you are serializing the form data. Are you using Javascript? What am I missing?

Comment: That's just it Steve, I'm not serializing it. I wanted originally to pass it with parameters only in the link_to, but I don't know how to use Javascript inside a link_to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely use the form. The only way that occurs to me to do this using a link is with javascript. Apparently when you do link_to :method => :post, Rails creates a form with javascript!. So I think it's definitely cleaner to use the form:

```
<% form_for user do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :role_id, Role.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The only problem here is where do I put the form submit button/link? I want it to be in another column. Is it even permissible in HTML to embed forms within tables outside the confines of a TD tag?

Comment: Stick the form outside the table. You can snag the link using Javascript and trigger the form's submit action. I don't know if you're using Prototype of jQuery, but in either case, just set up a `click()` handler to watch the link. Then in the link handler, you submit the form. However... this can be somewhat hostile to accessibility. It's your design call.

Comment: Ok, stepping back, thinking... You want each row to have a separate form. My interpretation is that you can put a form in a table cell so long as it is completely contained inside the TD. If you want a form per row, that would work. Otherwise do like I said before and shift the load to the Javascript to figure out what's being submitted.

Comment: He can't put the form outside the table, because there should be a form for each row. I don't think there should be a problem doing <td><% form_for ... </td>, but some HTML expert would give you a better answer.

Comment: Agree with @jordinl.... Just have the <td><form><select><button></td> all in the same table cell.

Comment: I actually have it like this: <table><form><tr><td><field1></td><td><select1></td><td><submit></td></tr></form></table>.

It's working, at least in Safari. Is this OK or am I violating a ton of HTML rules?

"Putting the load on Javascript", that's what's been driving me crazy. Do I just put a link out there, put a function in application.js, bind the function to the link, and do the submission that way? I have never bound any Javascript to anything before, which is why I ask.